# perfect powers of the form $\frac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Is there a natural number $k>1$ such that there are infinitely many
>   pairs $(x,y)$ of natural numbers such that $\frac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}$ is a
>   power of $k$?

---

In particular, is $k=2$ or $k=10$ good in this sense? (are there finitely or infinitely many solutions (in natural numbers) to equations $\frac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}=2^n$? or $\frac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}=10^n$?)

---

In case we put $x=y^2$, we would obtain equation $y^2+1=k^n$, which has been considered during investigations on Catalan conjecture.

Comment: If $k$ is (an odd power of) a non-square number and $u^2-kv^2=1$ is a solution to the corresponding Pell equation for $k$, then $x+y\sqrt k=(1+\sqrt k)(u+v\sqrt k)^m$ for any $m\ge1$ will give a solution to $(x^2-1)=k(y^2-1)$.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1054620

Answer (score 1):

Plugging in the fraction $\dfrac{x^2-1}{y^2-1}$ values $x=2^{2 n + 1} - 1;\;y=2^n$ we get
$$\dfrac{\left(2^{2 n+1}-1\right)^2-1}{2^{2 n}-1}=2^{2n+2}$$
so there are infinite pairs $(x,\;y)$ which give $2^k$

I think there are also infinite solution to $10^k$ but I still can't find a closed form

Hope this helps